# Pigeonhole Principle and Equivalence Classes

Tags: equivalence-relations, pigeonhole-principle

Let $A$ be a finite set with $n \geq 4$ elements and let $\rho$ be an equivalence relation on $A$. Suppose that there are exactly four equivalence classes: $C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4$. Moreover we know that $\mid C_1\mid = \mid C_2\mid = 1$. Let $a \in A$ be a fixed element that we know is in $C_3$.

What is the maximum number of ordered pairs $(x,y) \in \rho$ in which $a$ can occur $(a=x, a=y, a=x=y$)?

I'm iffy on equivalence classes, so in your answer could you help explain that as well. I'd appreciate the thought process behind solving this problem rather than just the answer since I want to learn how to do this.

Comment: I should probably clarify that I'm in an intro discrete math class -- so the answer should really only involve the pigeonhole principle and equivalence classes I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left|\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\rho\mid x=a\right\} \right|=\left|\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\rho\mid y=a\right\} \right|=|C_3|$
and $\left|\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\rho\mid x=a\right\} \cap\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\rho\mid y=a\right\} \right|=\left|\left\{ a,a\right\} \right|=1$

This leads to $\left|\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\rho\mid x=a\vee y=a\right\} \right|=2|C_3|-1$

**addendum**:

Denoting $P=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\rho\mid x=a\right\} $ and
$Q=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\rho\mid y=a\right\} $ you want to
find $\left|P\cup Q\right|$.

Note that $P\cap Q=\left\{ \left(a,a\right)\right\} $ so that $\left|P\cap Q\right|=1$

Note that $\left(x,y\right)\in P\iff x=a\wedge y\in C_{3}$ telling
us that $\left|P\right|=\left|C_{3}\right|$. Actually $P=\{a\}\times C_3$.

Note that $\left(x,y\right)\in Q\iff x\in C_{3}\wedge y=a$ telling
us that $\left|Q\right|=\left|C_{3}\right|$. Actually $Q=C_3\times\{a\}$.

So we end up with $\left|P\cup Q\right|=\left|P\right|+\left|Q\right|-\left|P\cap Q\right|=\left|C_{3}\right|+\left|C_{3}\right|-1=2\left|C_{3}\right|-1$

Comment: Could you elaborate this a little please? I don't understand how you came to the final answer or how $\mid \{(x,y) \in \rho \mid x = a\} \mid = \mid C_3 \mid$

Comment: I have added something to make things clearer.

Comment: Thanks! One last thing: would the complete answer for the maximum number of ordered pairs be 2(n-3) - 1? My thought process was that you want to maximize the size of $C_3$ so you only put one ordered pair in $C_1, C_2, C_4$.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes you are correct when it comes to $2(n-3)-1$ as maximal number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ characterized by $a\in\{x,y\}$. In my answer I changed $A$ into $P$ and $B$ into $Q$ because I noticed that the letter $A$ was allready in use denoting the whole set.

Answer (score 2):

If each element is considered as a vertex in graph, and each ordered pair as a directed edge, then each equivalence class will look like a clique(complete graph) in this graph.

Since a is in C3, it can only have relation with elements of C3.
In a complete directed graph, max no. of edges from a vertex = 2(n-1) + 1 self loop.(self loop since reflexive)

Thus your answer is $2*(|C3|-1)+1 = 2*|C3|-1$.

Comment: Can you check out my comment on the original question -- could you explain this in terms of pigeonhole principle rather than graphs? Thanks

Comment: If n > 4, how would you know the extra elements are in C3 or in C4. If they are in C4, then it wont make any effect as the answer clearly depends on cardinality of C3.

Answer (score 1):

The question does not have enough information to apply pigeonhole principle.